# Adding a second motion sensor to an existing motion sensor light

Tags: lighting, outdoor

I have installed a HeathZenith # 5412 motion sensor light. I have added a second motion sensor to that light around the corner of the building to pick up motion from that direction the second detector is a Defiant #Cd-5716.

I simply conected the white to white, black to black and red to red. I am still experiementong with the various controls to get them to work properly, but I waNt to be sure I connected correctly.

The lights have power as when they come on they flash (like a strobe), but the little red indicator light on the main light is not blinking (the one on the secondary sensor does blink).

Answer (score 1):

I have put multiple motion sensor lights (up to 3) on the same light string on circular driveways. The black to hot white to neutral With the light neutral and the red to the light string black. When any of the motion sensors detect motion the lights come on. If multiple sensors are tripped the one with the longest time or last one tripped will keep the lights on until it times out. All the sensors need to be powered from the same circuit or it may fry the controllers, trip the breakers. The only problem I have had doing this is troubleshooting when 1 sensor fails it takes time to find the bad one. This was prior to led lighting but it should work with led rated sensors also.

Comment: I wouldn't count on it working with LEDs. A lot of them are going to 12V internally, since.a 12v motion sensor component is half the cost of a 120V one, and 12V  LED heads are cheaper too.

Comment: Further to the information above, I noted last night the lights were on continuous, I went outside to check and as soon as I was in sensor range the lights started flashing.

Comment: What type of lamps are being used?

Comment: LED 75W - pars 38 2 flood bulbs

Answer (score 1):

It's hooked up correctly.  When you added the foreign sensor, that sensor takes the lead, so, the red light on the addition is a red light for both.